# Initial Quantity and Price in Shopping Cart React.js

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, shopping-cart, use-state

So I'm Building an react Shopping cart.I was able to add Total quantity and Total price functionalities but not able to display the initial price and quantity of products present in the cart.The products are fetched from backend using axios and storing it using useState.

Here's the code

```
const CartPage = (props) => {
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([]);
  const [totalQuantity,setTotalQuantity] = useState();
  const [totalPrice,setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
  const [loading,setLoading]= useState(false);

  const { enqueueSnackbar,closeSnackbar} = useSnackbar();

  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext)
  const token = authCtx.token;
  const userId = authCtx.userId;



  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    let queryParams = '?auth=' + token + '&orderBy="userId"&equalTo="' + userId + '"';
    axiosInstance.get('/Cart.json'+queryParams).then((response) => {
      //console.log(response.data);
      let fetchProductData = [];
      for (let key in response.data) {
        fetchProductData.push({
          ...response.data[key],
          productId: key,
        });
      }

      //console.log(fetchProductData);
      setCartProducts(fetchProductData);
      setLoading(false)
    });
  },[token,userId]);
```

Here's the totalPrice and Total Quantity Functionalities and they are called in increment & decrement counter handler

```
 const totalQuantityHandler=()=>{
      const totalQuantityCount=cartProducts.reduce((total,product)=>{
        return total+product.quantity;
      },0)
      //console.log(totalQuantityCount)
      setTotalQuantity(totalQuantityCount)
      //console.log(cartProducts)
    }
    
    const totalPriceHandler=()=>{
      const totalPriceCount=cartProducts.reduce((total,product)=>{
        return total+product.price*product.quantity;
      },0)
      //console.log(totalPriceCount);
      setTotalPrice(totalPriceCount);
    }

const incrementCounterHandler = (index) =>{
  const updatedCart = [...cartProducts]
  updatedCart[index].quantity++
  setCartProducts(updatedCart);
  totalQuantityHandler();
  totalPriceHandler();
  //console.log(cartProducts)
}

const decrementCounterHandler=(index)=>{
  const updatedCart = [...cartProducts]
  updatedCart[index].quantity--
  setCartProducts(updatedCart);
  totalQuantityHandler();
  totalPriceHandler();
}
```

So here is the JSX Part Of the code to display the total Quantity and total Price

```
 <React.Fragment>
    {cartProducts.map((product, index) => {
      //console.log(product)
      return (
        <CartCard
          key={product.id}
          Image={product.productImage}
          Title={product.productName}
          Price={product.price}
          Details={product.productDetails}
          removeFromCart={() => removeFromCartHandler("REMOVE",product.productId)}
          moveToFavorites={(event)=>moveToFavoritesHandler(event,product)}
          Quantity={product.quantity}
          incrementCounter={() => incrementCounterHandler(index)}
          decrementCounter={() => decrementCounterHandler(index)}
          onHandleCallBack={(value) => sizeChangeHandler(value,index)}
        />
      );
    })}
    <Divider style={{ height: "2px", backgroundColor: "#000" }} />
    <Box
      display="flex"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="flex-end"
      padding="10px"
      margin="20px"
      marginBottom="0px"
    >
      <Typography variant="h6">
        SubTotal({totalQuantity} Items): Rs.{totalPrice}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
    <ButtonGroup cancelled={()=>cartPageCancelledHandler()} continued={()=>cartPageContinuedHandler()}/>
  </React.Fragment>
```

I tried many things but it doesnt seem to work. Is there a better way of implementing it?

Comment: Can you share your html part of jsx as well?

Comment: Other than total quantity and price being derived state and shouldn't be stored in state because of this, your utility functions look correct to me. What is the issue? When are these functions called?

Comment: @Nayanshah Hey I have Added the HTML part of JSX , You can check it out !

Comment: @DrewReese Hey these functions are being called in the increment & decrement Handler functions which are used to increment/decrement the quantity.  So basically the issue is I'm fetching products from firebase and i want to display the no.of products fetched and total price of those products. Also i should be able to increment or decrement the quantity of products . I have edited the code part of the questions .You can check it out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that React state updates are asynchronously processed, so when you enqueue an update to the `cartProducts` state (i.e. `setCartProducts(updatedCart);`) it isn't using what the state will be updated to and instead uses the state from the current render cycle.

> I was able to add Total quantity and Total price functionalities but
> not able to display the initial price and quantity of products present
> in the cart. The products are fetched from backend using axios and
> storing it using useState.

You don't call the utility functions after fetch your data, so the initial `totalQuantity` and `totalPrice` state isn't computed.

Additionally, it seems you are also mutating your cart state when incrementing/decrementing the quantity.

```
const incrementCounterHandler = (index) =>{
  const updatedCart = [...cartProducts]
  updatedCart[index].quantity++ // <-- mutation
  setCartProducts(updatedCart);
  totalQuantityHandler();
  totalPriceHandler();
  //console.log(cartProducts)
}

const decrementCounterHandler=(index)=>{
  const updatedCart = [...cartProducts]
  updatedCart[index].quantity-- // <-- mutation
  setCartProducts(updatedCart);
  totalQuantityHandler();
  totalPriceHandler();
}
```

## Solution

Use an `useEffect` hook with dependency on `cartProducts` array to compute the  quantity and price state when `cartProducts` updates and remove the calls to the utility function from the cart updater functions. This way when the `cartProducts` state is initialized from the other mounting effect, and any other time the cart state is updated, the quantity and price will be recomputed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  totalQuantityHandler();
  totalPriceHandler();
}, [cartProduces]);
```

You must shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated.

```
const incrementCounterHandler = (index) => {
  setCartProducts(cart => cart.map((item, i) => i === index
    ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
    : item
  );
};

const decrementCounterHandler = (index) => {
  setCartProducts(cart => cart.map((item, i) => i === index
    ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 }
    : item
  );
};
```

In fact, because these two functions are essentially identical, I prefer, and suggest, to combine them and pass in the quantity delta. I also suggest using a curried function to save needing to use an anonymous function when attaching the callback.

```
const incrementCounterHandler = (index, value) => () => {
  setCartProducts(cart => cart.map((item, i) => i === index
    ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + value }
    : item
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<CartCard
  ...
  incrementCounter={incrementCounterHandler(index, 1)}
  decrementCounter={decrementCounterHandler(index, -1)}
  ...
/>
```

I would also suggest ***not*** storing the derived quantity and price values in state. These should be computed per render from the actual state. If you are concerned about recomputing when the `CartPage` rerenders but the `cartProducts` state has not, then you can memoize these values.

```
const { totalQuantity, totalPrice } = useMemo(() => {
  return cartProducts.reduce(({ totalQuantity, totalPrice }, { price, quantity }) => ({
      totalQuantity: totalQuantity + quantity,
      totalPrice: totalPrice + (quantity * price),
    }), {
      totalQuantity: 0,
      totalPrice: 0,
    });
}, [cartProducts]);
```

Comment: Hey I understood what you were trying to convey and implemented the changes as suggested and its working . Thanks a lot for your help!